# In Facebook: How to get User's list_ of_friends_ ID when User is offline[not Sign In]

Tags: java, facebook

**In Facebook: How to get User's list_ of_friends_ ID when User is offline[not Sign In].**

> We are Integrating facebook application in our website.
> Our website development in Java's GWT[Googlw Web Toolkit] FrameWork. We are refering "Gwittit" sample code
> We open facebook account for our website and want to show all users[friends] photo conected to Website's FACEBOOK account when FB A/C is offline [not sign in].
>
> We have  used apiclient.getFriendList() in that we get list of all user id [with photo]connected to Our website's fb a/c.But Problem is that we have to sign in first and we don't want that

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking into this problem myself, and as far as I know there are two possible ways:

1. **Create a Facebook *Page* not an *Account***
   It sounds like you are using a Facebook "Account" (a person) for your Website.  First of all, that is a violation of their terms of service because a Facebook account must be for a "person".  Second, Facebook does not allow ANY means of login other than through their servers, so a person, using a browser, must log in through facebook.com (which, for third party applications, usually happens in a popup) and then that authorization token will be sent to the third-party application for use with APIs.

   A Facebook page is perfect for this, because a Page doesn't need to be for a person only, and all content may be public. If the content is public, then you don't need an access_token at all.
2. **Request "offline_access" permission**
   An application may request offline_access permission for a user.  This means the token will not typically expire for a long time.  You will have to log in once, but then that access_token can be used for a long period of time.  Still, it sounds like you are using a Facebook profile/account which is not for a person and you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: Thank you for Reply
We Tried 2nd way ,as you say we have to sign in once to getting  friends_list_id[phto]. but in 2nd time it will ask for sign in again.
How to get access_token? How to avoid  expiration time?

Comment: Hello Friend
In our Website's facebook a/c we create 5 pages.
According to  1st  ways, How to access list of fans/friends_list_id[photo] in Facebook pages.
Hope for the Best Co-operation

Answer (score 0):

Use the following html to get users connected to Facebook page with photo when you're offline. Just change your page id:

`<iframe border='0' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=110000000000011&amp;width=243&amp;height=400&amp;connections=15&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false' scrolling='yes' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='false' style='border:0px; overflow:hidden; width:243px; height:300px; background-color: #03869E; color: white;'></iframe>`